# Why won't this program print the contents of an array as a string?

Tags: c, arrays

This program is supposed to store a reversed line of text and and print it out. I proved that the reversed text is stored in the array as I can print it out one character at a time, but it  will not print it out as a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Print lines in reverse

int main()
{
    int c=0, iget=0, iprnt=0;

    char getline[1000];
    char printline[1000];

    while ((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF){
        getline[iget] = c;
        ++iget;
    }

    while (iget >= 0){
        printline[iprnt] = getline[iget];
        ++iprnt;
        --iget;
    }

    printf ("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", printline[0], printline[1],
        printline[2], printline[3], printline[4], printline[5],
        printline[6], printline[7]);
    printf ("Result: %s\n", printline);
}
```

I have spent a long time on it and have tried many things including adding a '\0' to the next position after the string.  Didn't work.
I'd love to know why it doesn't print and what will fix it.

Comment: `char getline[1000]={0}; char printline[1000]={0};` ... `while (iget > 0){
        printline[iprnt++] = getline[--iget]; }`

Comment: what happens if someone enters over 1000 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second `while` loop you copy one too many characters, and you start from one character beyond the end of the input string. You also need to terminate `printline`.

Change:

```
while (iget >= 0){
    printline[iprnt] = getline[iget];
    ++iprnt;
    --iget;
}
```

to:

```
while (--iget >= 0){                    // <<<
    printline[iprnt] = getline[iget];
    ++iprnt;
}
printline[iprnt] = '\0';                // <<<
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/iiZ5Z2)</kbd>

Comment: I did that but still no go.  I forgot to add that I'm working on just a single word "esreveR" for simplicity.

Comment: This is the result I get

Comment: desreveR
Reverse
Result: 
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: 'code'desreveR
    Reverse
    Result: 
    Program ended with exit code: 0'code'

Comment: @Hendrik: click on the **LIVE DEMO** button in my answer to see a full working version with the above changes - it seems to work OK.

Comment: Hi Paul.  Where is that button?

Comment: @Hendrik: it's at the bottom of the answer - try refreshing the page in your web browser - if you still can't see it then the link is: http://ideone.com/iiZ5Z2

Comment: Thank you so much Paul.  You fixed it.  I did in fact try to add the '\0' but to no avail.  Thanks again.  I can sleep now...I think